# Using cythonized code causing "TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string"

Tags: python-3.x, cython, cythonize

I have a Python project that I would like to compile using Cython. After running the setup script, I try to run `test.py` and get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from root.pm1 import subsubsub as method
  File "C:\parent_path\root\pm1\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .f0 import subsubsub
  File "root\pm1\f0.py", line 1, in init root.pm1.f0
    import root.pm0 as runner
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _handle_fromlist
TypeError: hasattr(): attribute name must be string
```

When I use the second line of `root\pm1\f1.py` instead of the first one, the test script works as expected.

I've had no luck with changing `language_level` in the compiler directives and am unsure of where the issue lies. Am I doing something incorrectly? If not, is there a way for me to compile the code so that I can use the first kind of import instead of the second one?

The following code can also be found at: https://github.com/bpolinsky/example

---

---

Project Structure:

```
setup.py
test.py
root
  L __init__.py
  L pm0
     L __init__.py
     L f0.py
  L pm1
     L __init__.py
     L f0.py
```

---

root/__init__.py

root/pm0/__init__.py

```
from .f0 import do_thing

all = [
    do_thing,
]
```

root/pm0/f0.py

```
def do_thing():
    print("doing thing 0")
```

root/pm1/__init__.py

```
from .f0 import subsubsub
```

root/pm1/f0.py

```
import root.pm0 as runner
#import root.pm0.f0 as runner  # This one works!!

def subsubsub():
    runner.do_thing()
```

setup.py

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
import os
import sys

from Cython.Build import cythonize
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
from Cython.Compiler import Options

Options.emit_code_commments = False
Options.generate_cleanup_code = True


TOP_DIR = "root"
NAME = "root"
PACKAGES = [
"root",
]
INCLUDE = []

file_ending = ".py"
COMPILE_ARGS = ["-O3", "-Wall"]
LINK_ARGS = ["-g"]


def get_extensions(directory):
    extensions = list()

    for f in os.listdir(directory):
        path = os.path.join(directory, f)
        if os.path.isfile(path) and path.endswith(file_ending):
            path_split = os.path.split(path)

            ext_name = path_split[0].replace(os.path.sep, ".")

            module_name = path_split[1][:-len(file_ending)]
            if module_name != "__init__":
                ext_name += "." + str(module_name)


            extensions.append(
                Extension(
                    ext_name,
                    [
                        path,
                    ],
                    include_dirs=[
                        ".",
                    ],
                    extra_compile_args=COMPILE_ARGS,
                    extra_link_args=LINK_ARGS,
                )
            )
        elif os.path.isdir(path):
            extensions.extend(get_extensions(path))

    return extensions


# Build Extension objects
extensions = get_extensions(TOP_DIR)

# Do setup
setup(
    name=NAME,
    packages=PACKAGES,
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        extensions,
        compiler_directives={
            "language_level": "3",
        },
    ),
    include_dirs=INCLUDE,
    cmdclass={
        "build_ext": build_ext,
    },
)
```

test.py

```
from root.pm1 import subsubsub as method

method()
```

---

Additional Information:

- Python 3.6.0 (Enthought Deployment Manager)
- Windows 10
- Cython version 0.28.5
- Visual C++ 2015 x86 x64 Cross Build Tools Command Prompt (in an EDM shell) for running `setup.py`

Comment: It's kind of a pain to copy/paste everything into files. Any chance you can upload a repository to github or something like that?

My only suggestion just looking things over is to see whether it works properly if you don't compile everything. Also keep in mind that compiling python code like this doesn't usually produce any significant speedups.

Comment: @ngoldbaum Thank you for the suggestions! I'll try to get the files uploaded to a github repo later today.Thank you also for your comment regarding the speedups. I'm trying to do it more for security reasons than for the speedup (at this point)

Comment: @ngoldbaum I've uploaded the repository. It can be found at https://github.com/bpolinsky/example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `__all__` is a list of strings, not a list of functions.

If you make it look like this:

```py
__all__ = [
    'do_thing',
]
```

It should work fine.